# Migrations do meu app django não são aplicadas

Tags: mysql, python, django, migrations

Criei o arquivo models.py no meu app, criei todos os models, adicionei o appConfig no `INSTALLED_APPS` mas quando eu uso o `manage.py migrate myapp` ele não realiza nenhuma alteração no banco de dados mysql:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Pela maneira que descreveu o problema você criou o novo `app` (utilizando a nomenclatura do Django) `myapp` na "mão".

Quando o correto seria utilizar o comando disponibilizado pelo `Django`.

```
python manage.py startapp <nome_do_modulo>
```

Que você deve utilizar da próxima vez.

Para resolver este problema em específico você deve "copiar" a estrutura que seria gerada ao executar o comando citado acima.

Especificamente o fato de não gerar as migrations se deve ao fato de não haver o diretório `migrations/`, além disso dentro do diretório `migrations` deve haver um arquivo `__init__.py`.

Para resolver o seu problema portando basta criar esta estrutura citada, após isso será possível executar as `migrations`.

Além disso para gerar as migrations você deve executar o comando:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Pois ele vai gerar o diff (verificar a estrutura de tabelas presentes hoje em seu banco de dados, e gerar a diferença (incremento) baseada no que existe nos models).

Segue a [referência](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) sobre como este comando funciona.